# Where to store a password that you don't want in source control

Tags: c#, git, passwords

While debugging I currently have

```
#if Debug
   new NetworkCredential("myUsername","myPassword", "myDomain");
#endif
```

Would a good solution be to store the password in a file and I read the value (only in debug).  And then to add that file to the .gitignore?

Production would never read this value as it gets it from an NtlmAuthenticator from RestSharp of the logged in user.

Comment: Use environment variables or CLI arguments in VS -> those are part of VS and not your source code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good practice is to keep it in secret configuration file that you add to your `.gitignore`

You can do it with `file` property in `appSettings`, like:

```
<appSettings file="..\..\AppSettingsSecrets.config">
    <!-- whatever keys that are kept on source control -->
</appSettings>
```

and in `AppSettingsSecrets.config`

```
<appSettings>   
    <!-- SendGrid-->
    <add key="mailAccount" value="My mail account." />
    <add key="mailPassword" value="My mail password." />
    <!-- Twilio-->
    <add key="TwilioSid" value="My Twilio SID." />
    <add key="TwilioToken" value="My Twilio Token." />
    <add key="TwilioFromPhone" value="+12065551234" />

    <add key="GoogClientID" value="1.apps.googleusercontent.com" />
    <add key="GoogClientSecret" value="My Google client secret." />
</appSettings>
```

Comment: Would there be any issues in production where the appsettings points to "AppSettingsSecrets.config" and it doesn't exist?

Comment: If the file doesn't exist it will not crash, it will just be ignored. Of course, it means that you will not have access to any tokens/passwords/etc. that you stored in there (since they don't exist), and lack of these could cause a problem, but that is obvious enough. If you put these keys in `appSettings` of main file on production environment it will run just fine.